# Start service on Android O irrespective of app is running or not

Tags: android, android-service, javabeans, accelerometer, android-bluetooth

I am building an app which will be connected to a bean device (which gives accelerometer reading) via Bluetooth. I have to read the accelerometer readings every 20 secs irrespective of the app is running or not. Also based on those readings, I need to send the notification to the user. I think I have following options for this:

1. JobScheduler with startForegroundService method: Does it take care of Doze mode also?
2. Alarm Manager

Which options should I use to read the readings every 20 secs? Is there any better option?

BeanAPI doc: http://punchthrough.github.io/bean-sdk-android/

Comment: yes, doze does not affect foreground services

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is `AlarmManager`. Use a background `Service` as a foreground `Service` seems like an overkill for your situation. Implement an `AlarmManager` that checks on your `Service` periodically if it's running or has been killed and restarts it if latter is the case.

Comment: Why is Alarm Manager better choice than JobScheduler in this case?